# Get first date OR first date after gap

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a large table of customers and their policies that are set up like this (the actual dates can be throughout the year):

| Record | CustomerID | Name | PolicyStart | PolicyEnd | Agent | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Jane Doe | 20060101 | 20081231 | John Smith | Term |
| 2 | 12345 | Jane Doe | 20090101 | 20101231 | Sarah Po | Term |
| 3 | 12345 | Jane Doe | 20110101 |  | Sarah Po | Active |
| 4 | 12346 | Joe Dirt | 20130101 | 20141231 | Blake Lee | Term |
| 5 | 12346 | Joe Dirt | 20200101 |  | Blake Lee | Active |

I've been using a basic SQL query to get all the active accounts, by selecting the records where the status is "Active" and spitting out the list of active policies, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Status = 'Active'
```

| Record | CustomerID | Name | PolicyStart | PolicyEnd | Agent | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 12345 | Jane Doe | 20110101 |  | Sarah Po | Active |
| 5 | 12346 | Joe Dirt | 20200101 |  | Blake Lee | Active |

However, I've been asked to now provide a result like this:

| Record | CustomerID | Name | OriginalEffectiveDate | Agent | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 12345 | Jane Doe | 20060101 | Sarah Po | Active |
| 5 | 12346 | Joe Dirt | 20200101 | Blake Lee | Active |

The specific ask is to calculate the OriginalEffectiveDate column based on the policy start and end dates using this criteria: **Use the earliest policy start date as the customer's OriginalEffectiveDate, as long as there has been no break in coverage of one month or greater. If there has been a gap (or gaps), use the first date after the latest gap instead.**

So, Jane's original effective date would be 20060101, as that's when she first got coverage, and she has not had any breaks in coverage. However, Joe's original effective date would be 20200101, as he had a break (one month or greater) after his initial policy, and that is the first date after the latest gap.

I've attempted to mess around with CASE, MIN, MAX, and TOP statements, to no avail. I have no idea how to proceed. I believe in "teaching someone to fish", so please feel free to point me in the direction of a tutorial. The sticking point is the "one month or greater" and "after the latest gap" parts. I tried to search for a solution online, and I haven't come across anything similar, but perhaps I don't know the right way to phrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
SELECT Record
    ,Customers.CustomerID
    ,Name
    ,CustomerEffectiveDate
    ,Agent
    ,Status
FROM Customers
JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerID
        ,MIN(PolicyStart) AS CustomerEffectiveDate
    FROM (
        SELECT CustomerID
            ,PolicyStart
            ,DateDiff(month, PolicyEnd, Lead(PolicyStart) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerID
                        ,PolicyStart
                    )) AS gapMonths
        FROM Customers
        ) gaps
    WHERE gapMonths < 2
        OR gapMonths IS NULL
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    ) minstart ON customers.CustomerID = minstart.CustomerID
WHERE status = 'Active'
```

It's probably not the most elegant code, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution you can try is as follows using *lag*.

First get the gap in months between the current PolicyEnd and the next PolicyStart, it's possible to then find the most recent record for each customer where the gap was greater than 1 month.

Then you can select the minimum valid record for each customer *after* this point.

```
with gaps as (
  select *,
    case when DateDiff(month, PolicyEnd,Lead(PolicyStart) over(partition by CustomerID order by Record)) > 1 then 1 else 0 end b
  from t
), minrecord as (
  select CustomerID, Max(Record) mr
  from gaps
  where b = 1
  group by CustomerID
)
select Record, CustomerID, [Name], Agent, [Status], ed.OriginialEffectiveDate
from t
cross apply (
  select Min(PolicyStart) OriginialEffectiveDate
  from t t2
  where t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID and
    t2.Record > IsNull((select mr from minrecord where CustomerID = t2.CustomerID), 0)
)ed
where t.[Status] = 'active';
```

See this [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2bHb3Dlr)

Comment: This worked great on the demo Fiddle site. However, it appears that the proprietary online platform I have to use to run this query does not support "WITH", as it gives me the following error: WITH is not a recognized command. I tried to move the select portions into where the WITH names are used and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There's no mention of any specific platform other than the tagged SQL Server in your question? Naturally you're getting a solution that is 100% SQL server compatible!

Comment: An alternative might be to create a temporary table first to replace the CTE, so the `minrecord` CTE would be inserted into a temp table, `select CustomerId, Max(Record) into #temp from (gaps CTE here) etc`, selecting from the `gaps` CTE as a derived table, then reference the temp table in the main query.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. I tried running a command to get the SQL version, but it appears that is blocked as well. Due to the sensitive nature of my work, I'm not sure how much I can reveal about the environment, so I'm erring on the side of caution. As I inherited this work from someone who is no longer with the company, I've come in blind, and I'm not aware of all the limitations, unfortunately. I'll try your suggestion to get rid of the WITH clauses.